# How to get each element of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have a numpy array as follows :

Keys which will store some values. for example 
Keys [2,3,4,7,8]

How to get index of 4 and store the index in a int variable ?

For example the index value of 4 is 2, so 2 will be stored in a int variable.

I  have tried with following code segment

```
//enter code here

for i in np.nditer(Keys):
      print(keys[i]);

//enter code here
```

I am using python 3.5
Spyder 3.5.2
Anaconda 4.2.0

Comment: Don't use `nditer`; that's for advanced purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Is `keys` a list or `numpy` array

```
 keys = [[2,3,4,7,8]   # or
 keys = np.array([2,3,4,7,8])
```

You don't need to iterate to see the elements of either.  But you can do

```
 for i in keys:
     print(i)
 for i in range(len(keys)):
     print(keys[i])
 [i for i in keys]
```

these work for either.

If you want the index of the value `4`, the list has a method:

```
 keys.index(4)
```

for the array

```
 np.where(keys==4)
```

is a useful bit of code. Also

```
 np.in1d(keys, 4)
 np.where(np.in1d(keys, 4))
```

Forget about `np.nditer`.  That's for advanced programming, not routine iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. If the list is not too large, then:

```
where_is_4 = [e for i,e in enumerate(Keys) if i==4][0]
```

What this does is it loops over the list with an enumerator and creates a list that contains the value of the enumerator every time the value '4' occurs.

Comment: How would you do it if `keys` was a numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
for i in range( len( Key ) ):
    if ( Key[ i ] == 4 ):
      print( i )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all indices where the value is `4` using:

```
>>> keys = np.array([2,3,4,7,8])
>>> np.flatnonzero(keys == 4)
array([2])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a native numpy method for this called `where`.

It will return an array of the indices where some given condition is true. So you can just pick the first entry, if the list isn't empty:

```
N = 4
indicies = np.where(x==N)[0]
index = None
if indicies:
    index = indicies[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of [numpy.where(condition)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will be a good choice here. From the below code you can get location of 4.

```
import numpy as np
keys = np.array([2,3,4,7,8])
result = np.where(keys==4)
result[0][0]
```